# Module to import github content onto local drupal server

Tags: version-control

I want to be able to put content from github into the sites/default/files folder of drupal so I was wondering if there was a way to do this.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this? Is it a Library that you are needing? If so you need to look into the [Library API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) to do it the correct way. But I'm still interested in knowing the reasoning if that's not what you in fact want to do.

Comment: i want to use the import_html module to import sites but as far as I know i can only do that by moving my html files to that folder and periodically the github repo may have new html items added to it or modified. so i need to move files from github to this folder periodically

Comment: So you should be able to bypass the sites/default/files folder then. That probably shouldn't be used since you are going to be importing html and turning them into nodes with the import_html module. You could just create a folder on the server (could be outside your Drupal path or inside it but probably would be best outside) and clone the repo (use git to update when it needs to update) and configure that path in the html_import module. I mean you could make it anywhere you want but I would advise against using sites/default/files since that folder is unprotected and could open security risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own module. You can see part of the code [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166151/how-do-i-get-the-password-from-form-api-to-use-to-log-into-external-site). I put that code on a cron_hook.