# How do I get the password from form API to use to log into external site?

Tags: forms, users

I have these functions, one is for the Form API and the other, git pull, is called on a cron hook. The password is coming up blank and therefore the git pull is not working.

```
function cronmonitor_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {


  $form['cronmonitor_account'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Github Account'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('Github ID'),
  '#default_value' =>  variable_get('cronmonitor_account'),
  );

  $form['cronmonitor_pass'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password', 
  '#title' => t('Password'), 
  '#maxlength' => 64, 
  '#size' => 15,
  );
 ...more form elements....
}

function git_pull(){

  $localRoot        = variable_get ...
  $localRepoName    = variable_get ...
  $localRepo        = "{$localRoot}/{$localRepoName}";
  $username         = variable_get('cronmonitor_account');
  $password         = variable_get('cronmonitor_pass');
  $remoteRepoName   = variable_get ...
  $remoteRepo       = "https://{$username}:{$password}@{$remoteRepoName}";
  if( file_exists($localRepo) ) {
      shell_exec("cd {$localRepo} && git pull");
  } 
  else {
      shell_exec("git clone {$remoteRepo} {$localRepo} ");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a [known core issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/486544) by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the 
[Encrypt Form API module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/encryptfapi)